# How to change the color of a specified syntax in VSCode, without affecting the rest of the syntax that is colored by the theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, codehighlighter

I really like the V.S. Code theme, `Abyss`. On occasion I find that the theme makes my code difficult to read, the text rendered in the editor will look like it is blending into the background, therefore; I thought changing individual syntax color would be a good solution.

I want to be able to adjust a couple of color-tokens, while leaving the rest of the syntax unchanged. How can I select, and change the properties of color tokens, without impacting any other parts of the theme that's currently set in the editor?

[image]

I want to use the code syntax color of the `GitHub dark default` theme with the `Abyss` theme on the rest of UI.

[image]

[I found a site (click to see)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) that suggests changing the syntax colors with the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` property.

I am not able to understand that how can I copy the color configuration from `GiHub dark default` to the `Abyss` theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

V.S. Code users have the ability to style the syntax that is displayed in the editor, as well as the ability to style the editor its self — this includes the workbench, and all off the items in the workbench. To start styling the workbench, or syntax in the editor, you must first add the following JSON properties to either your user-scoped `settings.json` file, or by adding it to a workspace-scoped `settings.json`.

---

- `"workbench.colorCustomizations":{ /* properties here */ }`
- `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":[ /* properties here */ ]`

---

Example of a properly configured `settings.json` file:

```json
// "./.vscode/settings.json"
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.background": "#08182F",
        "sideBar.background": "#00132D",
        "panel.background": "#00132D",
        "activityBar.background": "#002040",
        "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#00132D",
        "tab.inactiveBackground": "#00132D",
        "tab.activeBackground": "#003054",
        "tab.activeBorder": "#003054",
        "breadcrumb.background": "#003054",
        "statusBar.background": "#005280",
        "sideBar.border": "#103050",
        "titleBar.border": "#103050",
        "statusBar.border": "#103050",
        "menu.border": "#103050",
        "contrastBorder": "#103050",
        "panel.border": "#103050",
        "editorRuler.foreground": "#103050",
        "tab.border": "#103050",
        "tab.lastPinnedBorder": "#103050",
        "activityBar.border": "#103050",
    },

    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": [
        {
            "scope": "punctuation",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#C4C4C4",
                "fontStyle": ""
            }
        },

        {
            "scope": "comment",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#246488",
                "fontStyle": ""
            }
        },

        {
            "scope": "string",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#98DAF4",
                "fontStyle": ""
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

There are many more properties that can be used to style your editor and syntax. A good resource to refer to is this template, its from the **YO CODE** generator, and it is what several theme designers use as a starting point when creating a new theme.

---

[Theme Template](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-generator-code/blob/main/generators/app/templates/ext-colortheme/themes/new-dark-color-theme.json) (e.g. you don't have to make a theme to use the properties).

---

The most useful tool at your disposal is when writing theme properties — just like in the example above — is VSCodes suggestion widget. The suggestion widget is most often used to auto complete code, however, its usefulness extends much further than finishing a line of text for you. If you type, *"background"*, while you are focused inside of one of the `colors`, or `tokenColors`, properties a whole list of available background properties will be available to choose from, and you are not limited to just background properties, the suggestion widget will work for finding borders, foregrounds, icons, buttons, inputs, bars, highlights and a whole lot more

---

Perhaps the best resource to read would be the [VSCode Contributed Page on Color-Themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme)

---

EDIT: If you download the GitHub theme, you can find the theme's JSON file, which is the source code for the *"Dark GitHub Theme"* in the following location:

*`$HOME/.vscode/extensions/github.github-vscode-theme-4.1.1/themes/dark.json`*

When ever you have a theme's source JSON Document, you can copy and paste individual properties from the theme you located, into your `./.vscode/settings.json` file using the properties:

---

- `"workbench.colorCustomizations":{ /* properties here */ }`
- `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":[ /* properties here */ ]`

---

**NOTE:** It takes some practice, and some reading to get good at creating themes, or even just configuring your current theme to customize it a bit like your doing now.

### ADDITIONAL HELP

##### I think it might help if I explain what it is your doing.

The workspace `settings.json` file, located in the root of each project...

##### `"./.vscode/settings.json"`

...takes precedence over all other configuration files, therefore, when a setting, or property is being configured in two files, and one of the files is `"./.vscode/settings.json"` then the configuration set inside `"./.vscode/settings.json"` will win-out the configuration in the other file, because `"./.vscode/settings.json"` overrides any configurations it holds, that are also held somewhere else. (I Hope that makes sense)...

Next to the workspace `"settings.json"` file, is the users `settings.json` file, which is located at:

##### `"$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json"`

So basically all you need to know at this point is your `settings.json` files are the word of the land, everything else is overridden. This is very important, because when you use the `settings.json` files to set color-token properties to highlight some syntax that is being colored by a theme, and your recoloring it because you don't like it, what you are doing, is overriding the theme's JSON file located in the themes extension directory @ `$HOME/.vscode/extensions`. If you don't set a property in a valid `settings.json` file, then the property will remain unchanged. This lets you select and choose which properties to change, by overriding the properties you don't like. And as I have stated in the comments and above, these are the properties you will use to preform the overrides.

---

- **`"colors":{ /* properties here */ }`**
- **`"tokenColors":[ /* properties here */ ]`**

---

Rather than trying to copy and paste entire themes, just try to change a single element. Once you succeed at changing one element, then you can try changing several in unison.

Comment: I just want to change the code syntax highlighting colors. I don't know which color is used for what, and individually setting could be hard. So, I checked the source JSON file of the theme [Github Theme](https://github.com/primer/github-vscode-theme/blob/master/src/theme.js). I believe from line 226 they have mentioned the code for color property. So is there any way to copy that and paste it in my setting.json file. Actually I don't have much knowledge about JSON syntax so can you pls help me?

Comment: The same way  that you use "workbench.colorCustomizations" & "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" is the the same way you create a theme. So they are often cross referenced, but any of the token properties you can highlight in a theme you can highlight in the settings.json properties that I just mentioned.

Comment: if you don't mind, then can you please look at my current [setting.json](https://gist.github.com/DarkstarDream/439bfbf6db008dadf430f76d64054ff8) file and can you tell me how I can add those code in my setting file

Comment: Yes, I am going to add it into the answer because I markdown isn't supported in these comments. Gimme a minute

Comment: @DarkstarDream Okay that's all your getting for now. Try and change stuff, if you cant maybe I can help more later.

Comment: I copied the code as you suggested but it's to have no effect. The code that I copied into the setting.json looks faded in compared to other settings, I don't know what it means. Can you pls take look to my updated setting files and point out my mistake [setting.json](https://gist.github.com/DarkstarDream/439bfbf6db008dadf430f76d64054ff8/revisions)

Comment: I sure hope you read everything I wrote, I took a lot of time to do that for you. I  just posted it in my editor and it worked. Try opening up a brand new project, and the only thing you will place in the project is a directory.  Name the directory `.vscode` with the dot in front of it.

Comment: then add a file to the `.vscode` directory called settings.json

Comment: so your files path will be `./.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: Open up settings.json and post in the code from the snippet.

Comment: I made a change to my snippet because I have a feeling you left out the curly braces last time you tried the code. Every-time you create a JSON file, add curly brackets to the file first like this `{ }`. And that's it, just the curly brackets. Then everything that goes into your JSON file will go between those two curly brackets. If anything is outside of them it will not work.

Comment: Is there any other way to contact you if you are comfortable because here it is hard to share media files?

Comment: You can contact me through my email, or gmail. I need to be able to see what your doing, and what the results are.  Like it would be nice to see a picture of your entire editor, with your settings.json file open so I can see how your formatting your Color-token/Color Properties.  https://GitHub.com/W3Dojo & W3Dojo@Gmail.com. We can open up a private room here on SO too, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your contact information, I have sent an email you can check that out, Also I would recommend deleting the above comment for your privacy.

Comment: Everything above is on my stackoverflow account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234378/discussion-between-darkstar-dream-and-jaydev).

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift+p =>preferences:color theme==> select Dark+(default dark)

Comment: Hey there. Welcome to the stackoverflow! thank you for responding and answering to questions. please add some explanation to your code to be more helpful. Thank you